# Telerik Reporting, Display the footer at the last page only

Tags: c#, telerik, telerik-reporting

I have an invoice with multiple pages, I want to display the invoice summary an the bottom of the last page (or the footer of the last page) only.

I tried to set the summary in the body, but sometimes it shows in the middle of the page depending on the data available.

I am using C# language with Telerik Reporting 2012

How could i do it?
thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using a *Page Footer* use a *Report Footer*.

Comment: And how to display it at the end of the last page. sometimes it is being shown in the middle of the page! thanks in advance.